# String returns an unhandled exception and does not take the input?

Tags: c#

I have just started learning C# in school after learning C++ and I am having trouble executing a compound interest calculator where you start with a specific sum and then you enter a percentage to multiply the sum by and return the number of months it takes to get to a certain sum. The compilator says there is an unhandled exception with the line where it says percent = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());. It says that there is an unhandled exception there and will not go to the for block.

```
using System;

namespace C
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double percent;
            double sum1 = 10000;
            int month = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the percent you would like to compound sum by, enter from .00 to .25");
            percent = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            for (double sum = 10000; sum <= 20000; sum++)
            {
                if (percent >= .00 && percent <= .25)
                {
                    sum *= percent;
                    sum1 += sum;
                    month++;
                }
                else if (sum == 20000)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"The number it took to reach 20000 is  {month}");
                    Console.WriteLine(sum);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error  ");
                }
            }
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't report unhandled exceptions. Either there's a compilation error or there's a run-time exception. Presumably it's the latter. Not surprisingly, `Convert.ToDouble` requires a value that can be converted to a `double`. Presumably `Console.ReadLine` is not returning such a value. What did you enter? Maybe use the debugger to see what that value is.,

Comment: It not only says that there is an unhandled exception, it should also tell you what that exception is, including the exception's error message. And when you look at it, you will notice that the stuff you inputted in response to `Console.ReadLine()` is actually not a valid floating point number representation. (Note that whitespaces are not ignored, and that whitespaces are not part of valid numbers. Also pay attention to decimal period vs. decimal comma. Whether it is period or comma for you depends on the region settings (locale) of the OS installation you run your program on...

Comment: I entered .12, .17 and other decimals within the range

Comment: What are the language/regional settings on your OS?

Comment: its a decimal period and it is USA language. How would I write it to represent a floating point number represantation, thanks!

Comment: Separate the Console.ReadLine() from the conversion, and assign its result to a string variable. Before converting it, print the inputted string back on the console, and -- importantly -- also the length of the inputted string. Tell us what you see...

Comment: I have more to the error, the exception says "Input string has incorrect format"

Comment: Alright, the exception is as suspected. Try doing what i said in my last comment...

Comment: Did you try to enter a value using a comma instead for the decimal point? What happens?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code and there was no exception on that line when I entered ".17". You've got bigger issues though. You are using `sum` as your loop counter and then changing its value inside the loop. That's insane. I don;t know what calculation you're actually supposed to be performing but it ain't that.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing probably a value that can not be parsed into the double. Try passing a value with a comma instead of a dot - or convert it from a dot to a comma.

Valid format to input ie.: `0,25`

Personally i'd do the parsing via `Double.TryParse(value, out var parsedValue)` and add some validation if parsing wouldn't succeed.